# Do I need to use -r with the command cp when using the find command in Linux?

Tags: linux, find

I have documents spread between multiple directories in a given path e.g. **/media/devicename/name_of_directories**. I used the `find` command to help locate certain files e.g. `.doc, docx`, etc

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/.*/.*\.(doc|docx)' -exec cp -r {} somedirectory \;
```

I know the command `cp -r` is used if I am copying files from a given directory but in the case of my `find` command, is it necessary and if yes or no, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -r flag in cp stands for recursive. You use it when copying entire folders, because it instructs cp to descend into the folder and *recursively* copy everything it finds within.

You don't need to do this when you're just copying individual files, because they are (conceptually) a single entity. As Ярослав Рахматуллин says, running cp recursively on a single file doesn't make sense, because there's nothing to recurse over.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Or type `man cp` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can not copy a file recursively, only a folder.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean I don't have to use the `-r` switch? What would happen if I did?

Comment: Using -r on a file makes no sense, thus you don't have use it. Nothing would happen. It would be copied as usual.